# I have 10 pages, I am on 4th page, then I want 2,3,4,5,6 as page numbers

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

If I have 10 pages, and the Current page is 4, then It should return 2,3,4,5,6 as page numbers. Like, the current page should be in between them and the page limit should be 5.

```
                            {pager.pages.map((page, index) => (
                                <PaginationLink
                                    className="pagination__link"
                                    type="button"
                                    onClick={() => this.setPage(page)}
                                >
                                    {page}
                                </PaginationLink>
                        ))} 
Output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I am using this pager() function currently:

```
    getPager = (totalItems, currentPage, pageSize) => {
    // default to first page
    currentPage = currentPage || 1;

    // default page size is 10
    pageSize = pageSize || 10;

    // calculate total pages
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

    let startPage, endPage;
    if (totalPages <= 10) {
        // less than 10 total pages so show all
        startPage = 1;
        endPage = totalPages;
    } else {
        // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
        if (currentPage <= 6) {
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = 10;
        } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
            startPage = totalPages - 9;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            startPage = currentPage - 5;
            endPage = currentPage + 4;
        }
    }

    // calculate start and end item indexes
    const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
    const endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

    // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
    const pages = range(startPage, endPage + 1);

    // return object with all pager properties required by the view
    return {
        totalItems,
        currentPage,
        pageSize,
        totalPages,
        startPage,
        endPage,
        startIndex,
        endIndex,
        pages,
    };
};
```

This funtion is used to get pagination array with all needed values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So I fixed it, It was some logic issue, which is fixed.

```
            // For Mobile
        // default page size is 5
        pageSize = pageSize || 5;
        totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

        // calculate total pages

        if (totalPages <= 5) {
            // less than 5 total pages so show all
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            // more than 5 total pages so calculate start and end pages
            if (currentPage <= 3) {
                startPage = 1;
                endPage = 5;
            } else if (currentPage + 2 >= totalPages) {
                startPage = totalPages - 4;
                endPage = totalPages;
            } else {
                startPage = currentPage - 2;
                endPage = currentPage + 2;
            }
        }
```